# Capturing the image of a web page using Firefox and Safari

Tags: c#, .net

I have a utility that I put together that uses the .NET Framework to capture an image of a web page so that I can use the thumbnail image to preview a page. There are sites which offer this service like websnapr.com, kwiboo.com and shrinktheweb.com. I would like to instead do it myself and leverage Firefox (Gecko) and Safari (WebKit) to render the image.

Is there anything available to do this currently? Is there a C# project that hooks into Gecko and/or WebKit to create images of a loaded web page.

My project is called WebPreview and it uses the WebBrowser control from the .NET Framework, but since that can be a bit outdated the rendered screenshots will not look as accurate as a recent Gecko or WebKit build.

http://www.smallsharptools.com/Projects/WebPreview/

Please post a comment for any Open Source projects which can help me.

Comment: I get a server error when I click your WebPreview link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a Firefox add-on called [Screengrab](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146)

Answer (score 0):

checkout http://browsershots.org/ its free and open. it says somewhere on the site what plugins and techniques they use...

Answer (score 0):

You can look a this project http://www.codeplex.com/url2jpeg. It uses Internet Explorer.